LTCGY - Let the corners guide you
Top and bottom row are complete. Complete the middle row. Explain why it's correct.


Here is the completed grid (one with and one without annotations):

 


The trick is

 This grid represents and corresponds to the positions of the cardinal directions. The N,E,S,W directions are represented in Braille. I figured this out by seeing the R1C2 and R3C2 tiles spelling N and S in Braille if you look at the dots surrounding the colors. I figured out Braille might have been involved by seeing the 6 dots surrounding each tile. I then, after the translation, thought to myself, hang on, N and S are abbreviations for North and South and the colors from which fit perfectly in their positions within the grid if you regard the grid like a compass. It also fit the title rather nicely (‘guide you’ and the abbreviations). So this had to be it- that is the grid representing the cardinal directions, I thought.
 

So

 The R2C1 and R2C3 tiles need to therefore spell W and E in Braille with the dots.

Also

 I spotted that if this was the case then the corners were just spelling out the other directions in their respective positions through a combination of the colors paired with the letters (e.g. since yellow is N and blue is west, yellow and blue is NW): NW, NE, SE, SW so the left and right needs to be red and blue completely just like the top and bottom to match the pattern. Tying it all together gives us this:
 

